# How to mock ServiceStackController Cache property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, caching, mocking, servicestack

Giving the following ServiceStack controller

```
public class MyController : ServiceStackController 
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Cache.GetAllKeys());
    }
}
```

and the following test class

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyControllerTests 
{
    [Test]
    public void Should_call_cache()
    {
        var controller = new MyController();
        // Mock here to access Cache, otherwise throws NullReferenceException
        var result = controller.Index();
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        var model = result.Model as IEnumerable<string>;
        Assert.IsNotNull(model);
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to mock `ICacheClient` Cache property to be able to validate test method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE:

As stated by the OP  in a comment. The practice of mocking the subject under test is one that is usually avoided. However with the poor design *(IMO)* of the underlying class that internally is tightly coupled to implementation concerns, making it difficult to test in isolation, then a workaround would be to override the problem member with something that allowed for more control when exercising the test.

---

`Cache` a readonly virtual property, but it can be overridden in a derived class. Use that as the entry point to mocking the desired functionality.

Create a derived class of the class under test and override the `Cache` property to return a mock that behaves as expected.

In the following example Moq is used to mock the subject controller and override the `Cache` virtual property.

```
public void _Should_call_cache() {
    //Arrange
    var controller = Mock.Of<MyController>();

    var keys = new[] { "key1", "key2", "key3" };
    var cacheMock = new Mock<ICacheClient>();
    cacheMock.Setup(_ => _.GetAllKeys()).Returns(keys);

    var mockController = Mock.Get(controller);
    mockController.CallBase = true;
    mockController.Setup(_ => _.Cache).Returns(cacheMock.Object);

    //Act
    var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    var model = result.Model as IEnumerable<string>;
    Assert.IsNotNull(model);
}
```

I reviewed the [ServiceStackController.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Mvc/ServiceStackController.cs) to realize that the readonly property can be overridden.

Comment: You shouldn't create a mock of the tested object (Controller).

Comment: @labilbe true. Explain how else in this case the OP can access and override the method in question. It would be the same as creating a derived class, overriding the target member and then running the unit tests against that derived class. Creating the mock just saves the heavy manual lifting involved.

Answer (score 2):

When [testing many ServiceStack components](http://docs.servicestack.net/testing) outside of ServiceStack you'll need to wrap it in an  AppHost either a SelfHost for integration tests or for unit tests you can use In Memory AppHost with:

```
using (var appHost = new BasicAppHost {
        ConfigureContainer = c => ...,
    }.Init()) 
{
    // Test ServiceStack Components...
}
```

You can use `ConfigureContainer` to register any dependencies ServiceStack uses, for Cache Provider ServiceStack uses a MemoryCacheClient by default so you shouldn't need to register anything.

Comment: ServiceStackController's cache property returns NullReferenceException even using BasicAppHost